# Mysql Query ignoring and where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a simple mysql query as shown below.

```
SELECT  `om_user`.`id` ,  `om_user`.`username` ,  `om_user`.`firstName` ,  `om_user`.`lastName` ,  `om_user`.`role` ,  `om_user`.`email` ,  `om_user`.`status` 
FROM  `om_user` 
WHERE (
id LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
username LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (

PASSWORD LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
salt LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
role LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
firstName LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
lastName LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
addressLine1 LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
addressLine2 LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
addressLine3 LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
city LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
county LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
postcode LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
country LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
email LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
contactNo LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
avatar LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (

STATUS LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
passwordRequestStatus LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
passwordResetCount LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
passwordResetSalt LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
passwordResetTime LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
createdOn LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
createdBy LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
lastUpdateOn LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
lastUpdateBy LIKE  'admin%'
)
OR (
active LIKE  'admin%'
)
AND (
active =1
)
ORDER BY  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But for some reason its ignoring the `active=1` condition. Instead of ignoring records who have the value 0 for `active` column, it still displays them.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to put parentheses around all of your "OR" clauses.  select ... from ... where ((a = 1) or (b = 1)) and active=1

Comment: Not totally sure but do you need to change 1 to True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewritten to put all of your OR's in a single paranthetical statement, and to remove the superflous parantheses around every OR clause:

```
SELECT 
    `om_user`.`id`,
    `om_user`.`username`,
    `om_user`.`firstName`,
    `om_user`.`lastName`,
    `om_user`.`role`,
    `om_user`.`email`,
    `om_user`.`status`
FROM `om_user`
WHERE 
    (
        id LIKE 'admin%'
        OR username LIKE 'admin%'
        OR PASSWORD LIKE 'admin%'
        OR salt LIKE 'admin%'
        OR ROLE LIKE 'admin%'
        OR firstName LIKE 'admin%'
        OR lastName LIKE 'admin%'
        OR addressLine1 LIKE 'admin%'
        OR addressLine2 LIKE 'admin%'
        OR addressLine3 LIKE 'admin%'
        OR city LIKE 'admin%'
        OR county LIKE 'admin%'
        OR postcode LIKE 'admin%'
        OR country LIKE 'admin%'
        OR email LIKE 'admin%'
        OR contactNo LIKE 'admin%'
        OR avatar LIKE 'admin%'
        OR STATUS LIKE 'admin%'
        OR passwordRequestStatus LIKE 'admin%'
        OR passwordResetCount LIKE 'admin%'
        OR passwordResetSalt LIKE 'admin%'
        OR passwordResetTime LIKE 'admin%'
        OR createdOn LIKE 'admin%'
        OR createdBy LIKE 'admin%'
        OR lastUpdateOn LIKE 'admin%'
        OR lastUpdateBy LIKE 'admin%'
        OR active LIKE 'admin%'
    )
    AND active = 1
ORDER BY 
    `id` DESC LIMIT 0,
    30
```

This will test all of the OR conditions. If any one of them are `TRUE` AND `active = 1` then it will return the record.

Also should mention that `OR active like 'admin%'` is superflous. It and `active=1` can't both be true at the same time.